# How to fetch data from firebase and put inside spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

> I was trying to fetch data from firebase and put it inside a spinner, I just want name of the nodes to be displayed on the spinner drop-down , But the entire branch of node is displaying as a single item in drop down.
> Please help me to fix this
> Let me show you my Java code

```
package com.example.presence;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class add_Attendance_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    DatabaseReference href;
    ValueEventListener listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_attendance);
        href= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.clear();
        fetchData();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void fetchData(){
        listener=href.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot mydata: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    list.add(mydata.getValue().toString());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Spinner Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsmAT.jpg)

Comment: first I want to know what field that you want put inside a spinner. Your problem is when get data

Answer (score 0):

Use a POJO model instead of plain string to store your data in the array adapter.

You can use `Gson` to populate your model from the repository which you get data and in your POJO model, override `toString()` method and return whatever you want your spinner to show!

**Kotlin version:**

```
override fun toString(): String {
    return when (persianName != null) {
      true -> StringBuilder(name)
        .append(" (").append(persianName)
        .append(")").toString()
      else -> name
    }
  }
```

**Java version:**

```
@NonNull
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + " " + supervisorname;
  }
```